# Edit a list while iterating over it (the pythonic way!)

Tags: python, list

So, I know how to do this, but it does not seem quite pythonic to mee. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
arr = list(range(10))
print(arr)
for n in range(len(arr)):
    # Perform som operation on the element that changes the value "in place"
    arr[n] += 1
print(arr)
```

Output (which is how I want it):

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they said. But if you want to do the operation while you're creating the list you can do:

```
arr = [u + 1 for u in range(10)]
```

I presume you're using Python 3. If you're using Python 2, then change `range` to `xrange` (unless the list size is very small), since the Python 2 `range` function returns an actual `list`, but `xrange` returns an iterator; the Python 3 `range` function returns an iterator that's similar to the old `xrange` (but with a few improvements).

If `arr` is an existing `list` that you want to modify without replacing the current `list` object with a new `list` object , you can do

```
arr[:] = [u + 1 for u in arr]
```

---

Here's some code that illustrates the difference between using `arr` and `arr[:]` on the left hand side of the assignment.

```
arr = list(range(10))
b = arr
print(id(arr), id(b))
arr = [u + 1 for u in arr]
print(id(arr), id(b))
print(arr, b)

c = arr
print(id(arr), id(c))
arr[:] = [u + 1 for u in arr]
print(id(arr), id(c))
print(arr, c)
```

**output**

```
3073636268 3073636268
3073629964 3073636268
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3073629964 3073629964
3073629964 3073629964
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

So `arr = [u + 1 for u in arr]` binds the name `arr` to a new list object, but `arr[:] = [u + 1 for u in arr]` effectively mutates the existing list object. "Under the hood" it creates a new temporary list object and then copies its contents to the old list object.

Comment: So the latter is efficient?

Comment: @Clausen: Well, it's actually a little slower than just doing `arr = [u + 1 for u in arr]`, but you won't notice the speed difference unless the list is large. But the main advantage of using `arr[:] = ` is that if you have multiple references to `arr` then they will remain valid, as Martijn explains in his answer. If you just use `arr = ` then those other references will still be to the old data, not the updated data.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
arr = [i + 1 for i in arr]
```

This produces a *new* list; in the above example I rebound the result to the same name.

If you have more than one reference to the list and need to alter it in-place (so the other references see the changes), assign to the identity slice (`[:]`) to update all indices of the list rather than rebind the name:

```
arr[:] = [i + 1 for i in arr]
```

This creates a new list object first, and Python then is smart enough to see that both lists are the same size and copy across just the elements before freeing the second list again.

You could even use a generator expression in that case to avoid creating an extra list:

```
arr[:] = (i + 1 for i in arr)
```

This moves the original elements aside to make room for the new elements, but no new Python list object is created for this. This should be a *little* more memory efficient.

Comment: Very pythonic indeed! Since I actually implement this in micropython, I do not want to create a new list (it already satrains my memory!), so I will probably stick to the in-place solution...

Comment: @Clausen: in memory constrained envs you should use a generator expression then.

Comment: @Clausen: glad you found more than one answer helpful! Unfortunately, you can award the 'accepted' mark to just one of the answers here. Pick the one that you feel was most helpful (and not picking one at all, if you can't choose, is fine too).

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehension:

```
arr = [x + 1 for x in arr]
```